# Can anyone please provide me the algorithm to find the information entropy and correlation analysis of an encrypted color image

Tags: math, image-processing

I have the mathematical formula. But I have doubt whether one can calculate entropy for Color Images ( normally i have seen for Black and White Images only).

```
H ( m ) = ∑ - P ( m ) log P ( m )
```

How should I calculate The value of P( m )

Secondly, I also have the formula for Correlation Analysis but don't really know how to find it out. I have the co relation formula

```
r (xy) = cov( x , y ) / squareroot(D ( x ) D ( y ))
```

It is said that x and y are greyscale values. what do you mean by greyscale values and how do I calculate those?

Comment: I imagine you are going to have to count up each of the differently colored pixels in the colored image and arrange them into groups of equal (r,g,b) values. Then work out the probability of each group from there to calculate the overall entropy. Also heres a good link explaining greyscale and how to calculate it: http://entropymine.com/imageworsener/grayscale/

Comment: If the image is encrypted, the entropy will be different from the original image so I am hoping you have the password - if not, you are stuck. If you do have the password, then the fact it was encrypted is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mark I am not trying to decrypt the image I am trying to evaluate the efficiency of my image encryption algorithm!

Comment: You are probably getting downvotes because you are not asking a question about code. You are asking how to calculate entropy, which I can image people could consider off-topic. Also, your title implies that you are not willing to do any work. You just want it given to you. If you would add an example image and code that demonstrates your attempts (i.e. an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask specific questions about your code, then I think you would probably get upvotes rather than downvotes.

Comment: @kkuilla I didn't add the code for a reason..My teacher doesn't want me to disclose the algorithm to anyone. Now I can add only that part of code but anyway I have found a way around it but just want to say that this time stackoverflow disappointed me! If you don't know the answer then just keep quite why give downvotes..you can simply add the comment and ask me to add code!

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:
To calculate the entropy, you need to estimate the probability of each RGB value - i.e. the count of pixels with that value divided by the number of pixel in the image. Than you operate the formula over all positive probabilities. There are two possible implementations of holding the RGB counts:

1. Simple histogram - 3-dimensional array 256X256X256, slow and memory consuming
2. Sparse histogram - hold a hash table with RGB as key and count as value.

The first choice may be better for very large images.

Note however that for rather small images, the probability estimation might be very inaccurate, as small noise may spread a single color to multiple bin. In the worse case all counts will be 1. To handle that problem, you may consider using larger bins - e.g. divide the RGB values by 4, so you only have 64^3 bins.

Question 2: You're talking about the correlation coefficient, AKA [normalize correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation

Gray-scale is just the common term for the value of pixel in a gray-scale image, usually in the 0-255 range.